# How do I find out the which Android devices will run my application?

Tags: android

Is there a standard way in Java to find out which Android devices (like tablet or phone) my application will run on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is the code:

```
public static boolean isHoneycomb() {
            // Can use static final constants like HONEYCOMB, declared in later versions
            // of the OS since they are inlined at compile time. This is guaranteed behavior.
            return Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
        }

public static boolean isTablet(Context context) {
    return (context.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout
            & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK)
            >= Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE;
}

public static boolean isHoneycombTablet(Context context) {
    return isHoneycomb() && isTablet(context);
}
```

or you can set the suppurted screens in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <manifest ... >
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    ...
    </manifest>
```

Visit the Google IO 2011 offical source code [here](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/UIUtils.java) if you want to more details.

I hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

There's also android.os.Build class. There's a number of static constants with monufacturer and model among others.